# How to enumerate values in a column according to their size?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame in which one of the columns contains real values. I would like to have a new column in this data frame that contains integer numbers indicating what place the real number from another column takes. For example, 1 would mean that the real number from the column with real numbers is the largest one and 2 would mean the second largest and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrame has a [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,100,10)})
df['rank'] = df.rank(ascending=False)

    a  rank
0  16     8
1  91     1
2  58     4
3  36     6
4  15     9
5  69     3
6  35     7
7  78     2
8  48     5
9   5    10
```

*Make sure you checkout the optional `method` keyword which sets the behavior in case of equal values.*